# AnalysisException: Table or view not found --- Even after I create a view using "createGlobalTempView" , how to fix?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, databricks

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v to streaming in my PoC.
I am trying to do join by registering dataframes as table.

For which I am using createGlobalTempView and doing as below

```
 first_df.createGlobalTempView("first_tab");
 second_df.createGlobalTempView("second_tab");

Dataset<Row> joinUpdatedRecordsDs =  sparkSession.sql("select a.* , b.create_date, b.last_update_date from first_tab as a "
        + " inner join second_tab as b "
        + " on  a.company_id = b.company_id  "
        );
```

> ERROR  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not
>   found: first_tab; line 1 pos 105

What wrong I am doing here ? how to fix this ?

> Some more info

On my spark session I ".enableHiveSupport()" set.

> When I see logs I found these traces

```
19/09/13 12:40:45 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
19/09/13 12:40:45 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=first_tab
19/09/13 12:40:45 INFO audit: ugi=userrw    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=first_tab    
19/09/13 12:40:45 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=second_tab
19/09/13 12:40:45 INFO audit: ugi=userrw    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=second_tab   
19/09/13 12:40:45 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_database: default
19/09/13 12:40:45 INFO audit: ugi=userrw    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: default   
19/09/13 12:40:45 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_database: default
19/09/13 12:40:45 INFO audit: ugi=userrw    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: default   
19/09/13 12:40:45 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_tables: db=default pat=*
19/09/13 12:40:45 INFO audit: ugi=userrw    ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_tables: db=default pat=*
```

> ```
> System.out.println("first_tab exists : " + sparkSession.catalog().tableExists("first_tab"));
>  System.out.println("second_tab exists : " + sparkSession.catalog().tableExists("second_tab"));
> ```

Output

```
first_tab exists : false
    second_tab exists : false
```

> I tried to print the tables in the db as below but nothing prints.

```
 sparkSession.catalog().listTables().foreach( tab -> {
            System.out.println("tab.database :" + tab.database());
            System.out.println("tab.name :" + tab.name());
            System.out.println("tab.tableType :" + tab.tableType());
        });
```

No output printed , therefore we may say no table created.

> I tried to create tables with "**global_temp.**" but throws error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: It is not allowed to add database prefix `global_temp` for the TEMPORARY view name.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateViewCommand.<init>(views.scala:122)
```

I tried to refer table with appending "**global_temp.**" but throws same above error

i.e

```
System.out.println("first_tab exists : " + sparkSession.catalog().tableExists("global_temp.first_tab"));
 System.out.println("second_tab exists : " + sparkSession.catalog().tableExists("global_temp.second_tab"));
```

same above error

Answer (score 4):

These global views live in the database with the name `global_temp` so i would recommend to reference the tables in your queries as `global_temp.table_name`. I am not sure if it solves your problem, but you can try it.

From the Spark source code:

> Global temporary view is cross-session. Its lifetime is the lifetime of the Spark application, i.e. it will be automatically dropped when the application terminates. It's tied to a system preserved database `global_temp`, and we must use the qualified name to refer a global temp view, e.g. `SELECT * FROM global_temp.view1`.

Comment: @BdLearner I would be concerned with this warning from your log `WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException`. It appears that it can not access the global_temp database. What happens if you replace 'createGlobalTempView' by `createOrReplaceTempView`? This function should create the view in the `default` database.

Comment: can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename

Answer (score 1):

Remove .enableHiveSupport() while creating a session. This would work fine.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("DatabaseMigrationUtility")
        //.enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate();
```

As David mentioned use global_temp. to refer the table.